# Orthogonality of basis functions of irreducible representations

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, group-theory, representation-theory, matrix-elements

Lets say I have two irreducible representations of a finite group $G$. Let the group have $l$ elements. The elements of the representation shall be linear operators $L$ that act on some function vector space $V$ that admits a basis,
$$
\Gamma_I : G\rightarrow L(V_I)\\
\Gamma_{II} : G\rightarrow L(V_{II})
$$

By fixing a basis $\{e_i\}$(where $e_i$ stands for the $i$'th basis function) for function space $V_I$ and a basis $\{f_j\}$ for $V_{II}$, we can express the linear operators as matrices. This yields two new representations $$\Pi_I : G \rightarrow GL(n_I,\mathbb C)\\\Pi_{II} : G \rightarrow GL(n_{II},\mathbb C)$$ where $n_I$ is the dimension/number of basis functions for the vector space  associated with representation $I$ and analogous $n_{II}$ for the vector space $\Pi_{II}$ associated with representation $\Pi_{II}$. By the trace operation we can assign each element of the group $g\in G$ a character $\chi_I(g)=\text{tr}(\Pi_I(g)) $ within the given representation.

We can then take the "list" of characters for each representations as vector and calculate the common dot product between the "character vectors". Schur's orthogonality theorem then tells us that this is zero for different irreducible representations.
$$
\frac{1}{l}\sum_{g\in G} \bar\chi_I(g) \chi_{II}(g) =\delta_{I, II}
$$

This is my understanding of the theorem.

My question is now how that helps with matrix elements and transition rules of the form $\langle e_i|f_j\rangle$. The objects of interest are the basis functions of the vector space, not the matrices or the traces of the matrices. I seem to miss the obvious but how does the theorem establish an orthogonality of the basis functions or connect at all to matrix elements? I am also not sure how the inner product is supposed to be evaluated at all even though I wrote down a bra-ket form. Nothing seems to require them to be functions of the same variables to begin with so I am also quite unsure about the inner product. How do I get from what I have defined to the application/evaluation of matrix elements ? Especially matrix elements where other operators are sandwiched in, like $\langle e_i|\hat O f_j\rangle$.

Comment: I do not get your point. Lets take the representation $\rho:G\to\mathrm{Gl}(V)$. Now, let $\{e_{i}\}$ be a basis of $V$. Then you can define the characters as $\chi(g):=\mathrm{tr}(\rho(g))=\sum_{i}\langle Ae_{i},e_{i}\rangle$, where $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is some inner product on $V$. You can easily proof that this expression is independent of the choice of basis. Of course, if you fix a basis, and write $\rho(g)$ as a matrix, then the trace of $\rho(g)$ is just the usual trace of matrices. But the point is that the trace of the operator $\rho(g)$ is independet of this choice.

Comment: More precisely, on the level of matrices, if you take two bases $\underline{e}:=\{e_{i}\}_{i}$ and $\underline{f}:=\{f_{i}\}_{i}$ of $V$, then you can always find a basis transformation, i.e. a matrix $T$ such that $e_{i}=T_{ij}f_{j}$. Then, if you write your representation as $\rho_{\underline{e}}:G\to\mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$ and $\rho_{\underline{f}}:G\to\mathrm{Gl}(n,\mathbb{C})$, then the traces are related as $\mathrm{tr}(\rho_{\underline{e}}(g))=\mathrm{tr}(T\cdot \rho_{\underline{f}}(g)\cdot T^{-1})=\mathrm{tr}(\rho_{\underline{f}}(g))$, using cyclicity of the trace.

Comment: @G.Blaickner I guess my introduction of the matrix representations was superfluous, but that shouldn't affect the core of the question at the end. My background is chemistry and I never had a course that explicitly covered representation theory so any suggestions to improve the question or fixing errors in the math, are welcome.

Comment: But what is the core of your question? My understanding of the question was that you basically asked why the orthogonality relation is independent of the choice of basis...

Comment: @G.Blaickner I am looking for the connection to this, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_rule  A simple character table allows me to evaluate the matrix elements between basis functions that form a basis for irreducible representations. But I don't see how this follows or why this works. You can replace the dipole operator with the identity operator to obtain a direct overlap matrix element. Knowing that two functions form the basis for different irreducible reps allows me to say immediately that the overlap integral is zero. I assume this is connected to Schurs theorem but how ?